# How did solr designers/architects/developers decide to use 8983 port by default?

Tags: encoding, solr, port

Some companies (e.g., google) is known to encrypt their names or the names of the products into port numbers (under which the service is running). I am wondering: is there a historical reason, why solar uses the port 8983 port (7574) be default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they just picked a number that was not being used at the time, see Chris Hostetter's mention in [this discussion](http://grokbase.com/t/lucene/dev/1524fwvj3q/give-solr-its-own-port-number) over changing the port.